# On the quaternary form $4n = a_1^2 + a_2^2 - a_3^2 - a_4^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

While working on a problem I ended up with the form

$$
4n = u^2 + w^2 - (a+p)^2 - (b-r)^2
$$

or more generally,

$$
4n = a_1^2 + a_2^2 - a_3^2 - a_4^2.
$$

**Question:** Does this form represent all positive integer multiples of $4$?

In [Dickson1927], I found this theorem which seems to mention universal forms for $4n$.

[image]

I am not sure if we can derive the form given in this question from this theorem.

**Update (Oct 24, 2022):**
If we take $a-p = u, ap = v, b+r = w, br = x$ and if $n = ap + br = v + x$ then we have

$$\begin{align}
a_1 & = a-p = u, \\
a_2 & = b+r = w, \\
a_3 & = a+p, \\
a_4 & = b-r.
\end{align}$$

As outlined in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4550693), factor $n = UV$ where $U,V,g \in \mathbb{Z}$ not necessarily prime and write

$$
n = UV = \overbrace{(U + V - g)}^a \overbrace{(g)}^p + \overbrace{(U - g)}^b \overbrace{(V-g)}^r
$$

We can see from the equation above that $U = p + b$ and $V = p + r$.

Since all integers may be written as $n = UV$ where $U,V \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have

$$
4n = a_1^2 + a_2^2 - a_3^2 - a_4^2.
$$

Therefore, this form universally represents multiples of $4$.

**References:**

[Dickson1927]: Dickson, L. E. “Quaternary Quadratic Forms Representing All Integers.” American Journal of Mathematics, vol. 49, no. 1, 1927, pp. 39–56. JSTOR, https://doi.org/10.2307/2370770. Accessed 23 Oct. 2022.

Comment: $a^2-b^2$ represents every integer not $2$ modulo $4$, so $a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2$ should represent everything.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Ah, yes! Thanks.